# how to join two or more tables into one in r using sql

Tags: sql, r, join

I have ewritten following code , I want to join these tables into one big table ; so how to do it in R using SQL

```
user_lessthan10per  <- sqldf("select count(uid) as count_of_students
                       from adopted_user_point
                        where points_scored between 0 and (1469*0.1)")
```

Next is

```
user_lessthan20per  <- sqldf("select count(uid) as count_of_students
                         from adopted_user_point
                         where points_scored >(1469*0.1) and points_scored <= (1469*0.2)")
```

,

```
user_lessthan30per  <- sqldf("select count(uid) as count_of_students
                         from adopted_user_point
                         where points_scored >(1469*0.2) and points_scored <= (1469*0.3)")
```

Now i want to join it into one table which contain count_of_students columns of these three tables.

How to do it in R i have UNION command but it is showing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  This will return one row with three columns:

```
select sum(case when points_scored between 0 and (1469*0.1) then 1 else 0
           end) as cnt1,
       sum(case when points_scored >(1469*0.1) and points_scored <= (1469*0.2) then 1 else 0 
           end) as cnt2,
       sum(case when points_scored >(1469*0.2) and points_scored <= (1469*0.3) then 1 else 0
           end) as cnt3
from adopted_user_point;
```

If you want three rows, you can use aggregation with `group by`:

```
select (case when points_scored between 0 and (1469*0.1) then 'Group1'
             when points_scored >(1469*0.1) and points_scored <= (1469*0.2) then 'Group2'
             when points_scored >(1469*0.2) and points_scored <= (1469*0.3) then 'Group3'
             else 'Other'
        end) as cnt3, count(*) as count_of_students
from adopted_user_point
group by (case when points_scored between 0 and (1469*0.1) then 'Group1'
               when points_scored >(1469*0.1) and points_scored <= (1469*0.2) then 'Group2'
               when points_scored >(1469*0.2) and points_scored <= (1469*0.3) then 'Group3'
               else 'Other'
          end);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have named the original selections differently,  erhaps 'u_0_10, 'u_10_20', 'u_20_30' to make clear that "user_less than30per" was really "user_btwn20_30", but now that they are R dataframes in the global environment, you don't really need `sdldf` to put them together:

```
user_under30per <- rbind(user_lessthan10per.
                        user_lessthan20per,
                        user_lessthan30per)
```

The sqldf function does offer UNIONs:

```
 one_and_two <- sqldf("select * from lessthan10per union all 
                                       select * from lessthan20per")
 all_three <- sqldf("select * from one_and_two union all 
                                       select * from lessthan30per")
```